# Read multiple .txt files and keep theme in a single simple array with php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to read multiple files and put them in a single array.

My code look like this :

```
      $directory = "./folder/folder/"
        $file_array = array();
        if ($condition == 'TRUE'){
        $file_array = array(
                    'file_1.txt',
                    'file_2.txt',
                    'file_3.txt',
                    'file_4.txt'
                );
        }

        foreach($file_array as $file){
                        $single_file_arr[] = file($directory . $file);
                    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($single_file_arr);
    echo "</pre>";

//OUTPUTS:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value4
            [1] => value5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value6
            [1] => value7
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => value8
            [1] => value9
        )

)
```

So how To use `array_merge($single_file_arr)` to keep all the arrays in a single array.

Where am wrong? I want to be in one single array.

```
//I WANT TO BE :

Array
    (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        [2] => value3
        .
        .
        .
        [8] => value9
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$directory = "./folder/folder/"
$file_array = [];
if ($condition == 'TRUE') {
    $file_array = [
        'file_1.txt',
        'file_2.txt',
        'file_3.txt',
        'file_4.txt'
    ];
}

$single_file_arr = [];
foreach ($file_array as $file) {
    $single_file_arr = array_merge($single_file_arr, file($directory . $file));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function, that returns contents of the file as an array. So you should use file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read contents directly as a string.

So change...

```
file($directory . $file);
```

to

```
file_get_contents($directory . $file);
```

and it will be like you needed.

Comment: Except they want an array of lines, not an array of each file's contents.